# GCC template argument deduction/substitution failed

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-errors, c++14

The code below compiles on MSVC but fails on GCC (4.6.3). Why does it fail and what should I do to fix it?

```
#include <array>

class Foo {
public:
    template<typename T, int N>
    operator std::array<T, N>() const {
        return std::array<T, N>();
    }
};

int main(){
    Foo val;

    // both of the following lines fail on GCC with error:
    //    "no matching function call...", ultimately with a note:
    //    "template argument deduction/substitution failed"
    auto a = val.operator std::array<int, 2>();
    static_cast<std::array<int, 2>>(val);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The following code, however, does compile (on both compilers), despite passing in an `int` for `std::array`'s template parameter.

```
template<int N, typename T>
struct Bar {
    std::array<T, N> buf;
};

int main()
{
    auto x = Bar<3, double>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the full text of the error messages you get, the compiler is complaining because the type for `N` in your template class is `int`, while the second parameter of `std::array` is `std::size_t`, which is an `unsigned long` on your system.

Changing your template's declaration to use `std::size_t N` will fix the problem.

MSVC is not complaining possibly because it recognizes that the value "2" works for either case, or because of a compiler bug.

Comment: Both clang and gcc accept [this](https://godbolt.org/z/14ZAi-) so it looks like more a bug on their side.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I was wondering about that too, but why then would the 2nd code fragment (in my question's EDIT) compile without error?

Comment: For MSVC it's a bug in our compiler. We've opened an internal issue to track it, thanks!